# How do I define a separator for the last item of a list?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code (the line starting with `<p class="category">` in particular) to print the respective categories of each post in an custom portfolio archive.

How would I modify the code so that on the last one, in addition to a comma, it used an ampersand? This way I could get it to print "Identity, Print, & Web Design" instead of "Identity, Print, Web Design."

The code:

```
    <?php  if ( have_posts() ) : $count = 0;
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $count++;
    $classes = 'portfolio-item item-' . $count;
    if ( $count % 3 == 0 ) {
        $classes .= ' ie-col3';
    }
    if ( !has_post_thumbnail() || post_password_required() ) {
        $classes .= ' no-thumb';
    } ?>
    <div class="<?php echo $classes; ?>">
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() && !post_password_required() ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail( $thumbnail ); ?></a>
        <?php } ?>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" class="title-overlay"><?php the_title() ?></a>

        <p class="category"><?php echo strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'portfolio_category', '' , ', ')); ?> Design</p>

    </div>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php portfoliopress_content_nav(); ?>

    <?php else: ?>

        <h2 class="title"><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.', 'portfoliopress' ) ?></h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Totally unrelated to your problem, but I am an English teacher, so I have to say something. You don't use a comma with & (or and). It should be item, item, item & item.

Comment: @LeeLoftiss Disagree, I'm a big fan of the Oxford Comma. Not that there's much risk of "item & item" being confused for one compound item, but the comma eliminates ambiguity.

Comment: I just went back and re-read the problem. I missed the first time where you were saying you wanted a serial comma, or, what you call an Oxford comma. I've seen that Oxford comma usage before but always just related it to some strange Britishism. In The U.S., most people don't use it. - BTW, if you found one of the answers useful, could you make it as the answer. If not, then I would suggest the strrpos() function.

Answer (score 0):

I use this function to display categories in a similar manner. The trick is to create an empty array and add your categories to that array.

To insert commas, use `implode(', ', $array)` which creates: Red, Blue, Green

If you want to add the ampersand, you can use `array_pop($array)` which will remove the last element. Just check that the array is at least 3 in length.

```
// Display categories tagged by the post.
if (get_the_category()) {

  // Add our categories to a new array
  $category_list = array();

  // Sift through every category, optionally doing some maintenence.
  foreach(get_the_category() as $cat) {
    if ( $cat->name == 'uncategorized' ) continue; // Skip uncategorized category

    // Create an <a> element for our category
    $category_list[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s" title="View all posts in %s">%s</a>',
        esc_attr( get_category_link( $cat->term_id ) ),
        esc_attr( $cat->name ),
        $cat->name
    );
  }

  // If we have multiple categories, display a list
  if (count($category_list) > 2) {
      // Take the last category off, then add it on after an ampersand.
      $last_category = array_pop($category_list);

      echo sprintf( 'Categories: %s &amp; %s'
          implode(', ', $category_list),
          $last_category
      );
  } else {
      if (count($category_list) > 1)
        echo 'Categories: ', implode(', ', $category_list);
      elseif (count($category_list) == 1)
        echo 'Category: ', $category_list[0];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

go through the list of posts twice. The first time just get a total count, no processing of the data. The second time, watch the count. When you get to the next to the last item, instead of using a ',' use '&'.